# Combinatorics - Find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in...

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Would someone be able to help me figure out these two binomial coefficient problems using generating functions? Its a rough concept for me to understand, so a good explanation would be very much appreciated!

$a$) $(1-x)^8$

$b$) $(1-4x)^{-5}$

Thank you in advanced for your help!!!

Comment: What order polynomial is a)? Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem for b).

Comment: What do you mean by order? (Sorry, as mentioned earlier, I'm still new to this..)

Comment: As I am looking at this, I don't believe there is even an x^12 coefficient in (1-x)^8. Am I right on this fact?

Comment: Well, there is a coefficient, but it is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$(1-x)^8=1-8 x+28 x^2-56 x^3+70 x^4-56 x^5+28 x^6-8 x^7+x^8.$$ The highest power in this polynomial is $x^8$. Thus the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is $0$.

Consider $${1\over (1-4x)^5}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{n+5-1\choose n}4^nx^n.$$ Let $n=12$. The coefficient of $x^{12}$ is ${16\choose 12}4^{12}=30534533120$.

We know that $${1\over (1-x)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{n+k-1\choose n}x^n.$$
We can use this fact to calculate the coefficients of $x^n$ as we please.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot! I have an addition question (more like check my logic on this:

Comment: $(1+x)^8$ does not have a coefficient, but $(1+x)^-8$ does?
reason: if we let -y = x, then we have $(1-y)^-80$ = $\frac{1}{(1-y)^8}$, in which the twelfth coefficient is C(19,12)?

Comment: That is correct! Very nice! :)